# functional update of set structure in python

Tags: python, functional-programming, set

Is there a functional update-like method of adding elements to a set in python ?

```
myset = set(somelist)
myset.add('timestamp') 
#myset memory location has been mutated to contain 'timestamp'
```

Whereas I would like

```
myset = set(somelist).add('timestamp') #mutation or not, it's functional for all I care
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `union` method :

```py
myset = set(somelist).union(['timestamp'])
```